# Single Sign On query in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I implemented single sign on by reading this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/aspnetsinglesignon.aspx

However, I have a question from the extensibility point of view. Will the method shown above work if I host 1st application on 1 machine and 2nd application on different machine. I don't have 2 different servers at the moment otherwise I would have verified it myself. Anybody has any experience?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work as long as your encryption and validation keys defined in the machine.config on both servers are exactly the same. If you forget this it won't work since a cookie encrypted on one server won't be decrypted on the other server(s).

The article suggests putting these keys on Web.config. That's a valid approach, but if you need SSO on multiple websites, it's probably best to define it in `machine.config` provided you have control over this and all your apps in the same server are meant to share this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the encryption and validation keys matching, you also need the cookie name to be identical on both machines as well.

If your applications and servers may be a mix of .net3.5/.net4.0 and iis6/iis7, you also should explicitly state the hash algorithm. Microsoft introduced a breaking change from 3.5 to 4.0 by changing the default hash algorithm from SHA1 to SHA256. This is described here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidHoerster/archive/2010/06/15/asp.net-membership-password-hash----.net-3.5-to-.net-4.aspx

but in essence you will likely want the following in your web.config or machine.config:

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey validation="SHA1" />
  ...
</system.web>

<system.web>
  <membership defaultProvider="myMembership" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  ...
</system.web>
```